# Saving CheckBox state from RecyclerView Adapter class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

So I want to save CheckBox state via SharedPreferences in RecyclerView adapter class like this:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                        title.setPaintFlags(title.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        title.setAlpha(0.5f);
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit().putBoolean("checkBox", checkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                    } else if (!checkBox.isChecked()){
                        title.setPaintFlags(0);
                        title.setAlpha(0.8f);
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit().putBoolean("checkBox", checkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Dont' mind the paint flags.

And I'm retrieving the data in my activity like this (in onCreate):

```
 checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDoneOrNotNaListi);
        boolean checked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("checkBox", false);
        checkBox.setChecked(checked);
```

And getting NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Make sure `checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDoneOrNotNaListi);` is after `setConentView()` in `onCreate()`

Comment: It is after set content view

Comment: Well according to the error `checkBox ` is equal to `null`. Have you checked the id to make sure it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I've checked and it is correct

Comment: If `checkbox` is inside the `recyclerView` then you need to get the `checkBox` from the `recyclerView`'s `ViewHolder`

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * save selected <position, checkBoxState>
 */
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItem = new new SparseBooleanArray(listData.size());
/**
 * true: allow checkbox change, else otherwise
 * purpose update checkbox state on bind data
 */
private boolean isAllowOnCheckChange = true;
```

@onBindViewHolder

```
isAllowOnCheckChange = false;
itemHolder.checkBox.setChecked(mSelectedItem.get(position));
isAllowOnCheckChange = true;
itemHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isAllowOnCheckChange)
                    mSelectedItem.put(position, isChecked);
            }
        });
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score -1):

In `onBindViewHolder()` in the adapter class, you could put something like this:

```
boolean checked = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("checkBox", false);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(checked);
```

Then your `ViewHolder` should look something like this:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CheckBox checkBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDoneOrNotNaListi);
    }
}
```

The `onClickListener()` could look something like this:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit().putBoolean("checkBox0", checkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit().putBoolean("checkBox1", checkBox.isChecked()).commit();
                        break;
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well I did just that, and in my activity left the code as it was in the first post and still getting that same NullPointer

Comment: Wow, it works now but all are checked by default and when I restart the app they still remain checked evem though i uncheck them

Comment: You will need to create a different variable in the `sharedPreferences` for each check box, or find some other way to remember which ones were checked and which weren't.